# Bash shell scripting rsync

Tags: linux, bash

How can I recursively copy all the contents of one folder to another folder using RSYNC?
For example: sourcefolder destinationfolder

Comment: `man rsync` will give you all the help you need.

Answer (score 6):

The typical usage:

```
  rsync -avz src dest
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you already know the command, -r is for recursive. -a is even better as it also preserves timestamps, symbolic links, and so on.

When I use rsync, I always refer [to this site](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/), as it is easier to read as a man page.